# PowerQuery: Getting error info when it's too late to `try`?

Tags: powerquery

## Short Version

In PowerQuery, when the error occurs before I'm able to use `try`, how do I catch an error and get the reason and message strings?

## Long Version

In PowerQuery (using Excel if that matters),

```
OleDb.DataSource(
  MyConnectionString,
  [Query="SELECT * FROM NonExistingTable"]
)
```

returns an error. Great. I want that because I'm trying to make a quick and dirty tool that grabs data from multiple tables, but some people don't have access to all tables and who knows what else will happen in the future. However, I want to handle that error so it degrades gracefully, preferably presenting an explanation to the user based on the info within the error.

Therefore, I attempted error handling with `try`, like so:

```
try OleDb.DataSource(
  MyConnectionString,
  [Query="SELECT * FROM NonExistingTable"]
)
```

and I had expected it to return something like

```
[
  HasError = true,
  Error = [
    Reason = "OLE DB",
    Message = "Invalid object name: 'NonExistingTable'.",
    Details = ...
  ]
]
```

but instead, what's returned is

```
[
  HasError = false,
  Value = Error
]
```

where `Error` is an error object containing the information I want.
I had then tried to make a workaround with something like

```
let
  tryRecord = try OleDb.DataSource(MyConnectionString, [Query="SELECT * FROM NonExistingTable"]),
  ret = if (tryRecord[HasError]) then
    // It's an error
    tryRecord
  else try
    // If Value.Type() doesn't throw an error then tryRecord[Value] isn't an error, so return it.
   (if Value.Type(tryRecord[Value]) = null then null else tryRecord)
  otherwise
    // tryRecord[Value] contains an error!
    try error tryRecord[Value]
in
  ret
```

but `try error tryRecord[Value]` is not unpacking the error object within tryRecord[Value] like I had hoped.

How do I get the reason and message strings from an error object?

Comment: `let Source = OleDb..., result = try Value.Type(Source) in if result[HasError] then result[Error] else Source`. Note that we're not doing anything with the result of `Value.Type` here, it's just to force evaluation.

Comment: Agreed. I couldn't figure out how to say if it's an error. So that part of the code never returns `null`. It either returns `tryRecord` or the error throws the code into `otherwise`.

Comment: To be clear, the expression in my comment should be what you're looking for, in the sense that the `result[Error]` branch contains the error record with the message unpacked. You don't want to stuff this into `error` again since there's no point to that, you'll just get back the original error! If you're OK with the user getting that there's no need to `try` in the first place.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I had misread your comment. What you did works!

Comment: So, the answer is that if you `try` to do something with an error, it bubbles up a try record, so I can convert an error into a try record by attempting `Value.Type` or something else. Thank you. If you want credit for it, Jeroen, you should write an answer instead of just a comment. Thank you.

Comment: Emphasizing that [`error ` is a language keyword to throw exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/m-spec-error-handling) using `error Foo` is similar to `throw Exception` or `raise Exception` -- then you use `try foo` and `try foo otherwise bar` as `try{..} catch {.. }` expressions -- Finally, [Error.Record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/error-record) creates an `Exception` or `ErrorRecord` that `error` can throw

Comment: If you want to get the value in one statement, you need to use parenthesis `(try maybeAnError)[Value]` or if you want to prevent errors when value doesn't exist `(try maybeAnError)[Value]? ?? 'defaultValue'`

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Write this as an answer and I'll pick it.